# Adb stopped by some reason?

Tags: android, adb

Sometimes my adb disconnected. Why i am getting like this : -

```
[2011-09-27 17:39:43 - adb]
[2011-09-27 17:39:43 - adb]This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an     unusual way.
[2011-09-27 17:39:43 - adb]Please contact the application's support team for more     information.
[2011-09-27 17:39:49 - DeviceMonitor]Adb connection Error:An existing connection was     forcibly closed by the remote host
[2011-09-27 17:39:51 - DeviceMonitor]Connection attempts: 1
[2011-09-27 17:39:53 - DeviceMonitor]Connection attempts: 2
[2011-09-27 17:39:55 - DeviceMonitor]Connection attempts: 3
[2011-09-27 17:39:57 - DeviceMonitor]Connection attempts: 4
[2011-09-27 17:39:58 - DeviceMonitor]Connection attempts: 5
[2011-09-27 17:40:00 - DeviceMonitor]Connection attempts: 6
[2011-09-27 17:40:02 - DeviceMonitor]Connection attempts: 7
[2011-09-27 17:40:04 - DeviceMonitor]Connection attempts: 8
[2011-09-27 17:40:06 - DeviceMonitor]Connection attempts: 9
[2011-09-27 17:40:08 - DeviceMonitor]Connection attempts: 10
[2011-09-27 17:40:10 - DeviceMonitor]Connection attempts: 11
```

Any help appreciated?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Due to some reason sometimes adb gets disconnected, so in that case you have to reset the adb.

Go to `DDMS->Devices` and you will see `reset adb` option in `View Menu` besides `Screen Capture` option.

[image]

Comment: I will call that `Reset ADB` rather! =)
And thanks, that works.

Answer (score 6):

Another way to restart the adb is through terminal or command line.  Depending on if you have adb in your path just type:

$ adb kill-server

$ adb start-server

If adb is not in your path then:

$ path-to-sdk/platform-tools/adb kill-server

$ path-to-sdk/platform-tools/adb start-server

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, this is correct but this takes sometime to go to cmd and perform instead we can directly do it from eclipse itself. Thanks.

Comment: Guys the question is Why does the adb gets disconneted but not how to start it again.

Comment: Cmd worked it for me. For some reason it would not reset when called from eclipse.

Comment: @PlasticSturgeon yea it is very on/off - sometime restarting eclipse is the only thing that will fix my problems.

Answer (score 2):

Loose connection of the cable connecting the device i hope.

Answer (score 2):

Go to `DDMS->Devices` and you will see `restart adb` option in View Menu besides Screen Capture option.

Answer (score 0):

In preferences change the android/DDMS log settings from "error" to "debug".  After this you should be able to use the Reset adb option.